# How to display the suggested word in textView based on the selected code from spinner?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have this lookup json where it display suggested word. If I input "T" in the editText all values that has "t" in its word will display in the suggested list.

It's already implemented.

what I wanted to do is, if I select a code in spinner, the suggested display value will be based on the selected code.

Here is my json for my spinner

```
{
    "products"{
        "BI-BIKE",
        "CA-CAR",
        "MO-MOTOR",
        "TR-TRICYCLE"
    }
}
```

Here is my json for lookupjson

```
{
    "BI": {
        "brand": {
            "GNT": "GIANT",
            "TRL": "TREK",
            "CNN": "CDALE",
            "STC": "SANTA",
        }
    },
    "CA": {
        "brand": {
            "AIC": "AICHI",
            "BRI": "BRIGDESTONE",
            "CON": "CONTINENTAL",
            "DUN": "DUNLOP",
        }
    },
    "MO": {
        "brand": {
            "CAN": "CANON",
            "CAS": "CIO",
            "FUJ": "FUJ",
            "GPR": "PRO",
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is

If I select "BI" , and I type "T" in the editText field, all values from "BI" code with "t" will display.

first I need to get the first word before the (-) for me to check the code After getting the code check first the code before displaying suggested words.

here is the code where I display the suggested values without the connection from the selected in spinner.

```java
private void loadLookupCategoryJson() {

        mLookupProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayStringLookupProduct = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadLookupBrandJSON());
            Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) json.get(key);
                JSONObject brand = obj.getJSONObject(Keys.CATEGORY_BRAND);
                JSONObject desc = obj.getJSONObject(Keys.CATEGORY_DESC);

                 final String productCode = mProductDescriptionCd.split("-")[0];

                if (productCode.equals(brand)){
                    Iterator<String> brandKeys = brand.keys();
                    while (brandKeys.hasNext()) {
                        String bKey = brandKeys.next();
                        mArrayStringLookupProduct.add((String) brand.get(bKey));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Expected Result**

Selected Products: **BI-BIKE**

Inputted text from TextField: **T**

Display suggested word:

```
                      GIANT
                      TREK
                      SANTA
```

**Actual Result**

Selected Products: **BI-BIKE**

Inputted text from TextField: **T**

Display suggested word:

```
                      GIANT
                      TREK
                      SANTA
                  BRIGDESTONE
                  CONTINENTAL
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Comment: I already solved my problem. Thanks though!